# Notifications with Socket.io - how to emit to a specific user/recipient?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I want to implement a simple notification system. When `user1` likes `user2`'s post, `user2` should get a real-time notification from `user1`.

Here is a part of the client function (Redux action) where someone likes a post:

```
.then(() => {
  const socket = require("socket.io-client")(
    "http://localhost:5000"
  );
  socket.emit("like", user, post);
});
```

Here is the server socket function where a notification is created after `user1` likes `user2`'s post:

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("like", async (user, post) => {
        if (!post.post.likedBy.includes(user.user._id)) {
            const Notification = require("./models/Notification");

            let newNotification = new Notification({
                notification: `${user.user.username} liked your post!`,
                sender: user.user._id,
                recipient: post.post.by._id,
                read: false,
            });

            await newNotification.save();

            io.emit("notification");
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the client function after the notification is created:

```
socket.on("notification", () => {
        console.log("liked");
});
```

Now the problem with this is the `console.log('liked')` appears for both `user1` and `user2`. How can I emit to **only that user that receives the notification**? How can socket.io find this specific `user2` that receives the notification from `user1`?

Comment: Not only user1 and user2 but all users will receive the notification here

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to solve. I only want the `recipient` to receive a notification.

Comment: Does my below answer works ?

Comment: I will try later today and get back to you, thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should store a list (array or object) of all users like this :

(note that the list has to be updated when a user `connects` or `leaves` the socket server)

```js
// an example of structure in order to store the users
const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    socket: socket
  },
  // ...
];
```

And then you can target the post owner and send him a notification like this :

```js
// assuming the the 'post' object contains the id of the owner
const user = users.find(user => user.id == post.user.id);
// (or depending of the storage structure) 
// const user = users[post.user.id]
user.socket.emit('notification');
```

Here an example :

```js
const withObject = {};
const withArray = [];

io.on('connection', socket => {
  const user = { socket : socket };
  socket.on('data', id => {
    // here you do as you want, if you want to store just their socket or another data, in this example I store their id and socket
    user.id = id;
    withObject[id] = user;
    withArray[id] = user;
    // or withArray.push(user);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    delete withObject[user.id];
    delete withArray[user.id];
    // or let index = users.indexOf(user);
    // if(index !=== -1) users.splice(index, 1);

  });
});
```

There is plenty way of achieving what i'm trying to explain but the main idea is to link the socket with an index (user id for example) in other to retrieve it later in the code.

Comment: All the `users` are in the MongoDB database. How can I store each of them in the `socket`?

Comment: You can store their socket in a variable on the server. When a user connects to the socket server, you add him as an object (his id and his socket), in a global array. When he disconnects, you remove him from the global array.

Comment: Could you please help with adding them to the socket server? I see there is an array but how do they get added to it automatically?

Comment: On 'connection' event you can save the socket in an array (or object). In order the store the id you have to emit another event like a 'data' event. I add the code in my answer

Comment: Thank you for your patience. So do I need to emit to the recipient's socket.id? Nothing happens with `user.socket.emit('notification');`

Comment: Yes that should work,  does the socket property is correctly defined ?

Comment: I think it's working now. :) Appreciate it!!! Been struggling with it for hours.

Comment: How would you delete the reference on disconnect?

Comment: Nice to hear that ! I will add examples for deletion in few minutes

Comment: After I manullay refresh the app, it doesn't emit for some reason. Is it because I didn't disconnect the user?

Comment: I uptated the example, does this solves your problem ?

Comment: Thank you for your effort but I don't know why, after refreshing manually it does not emit to the user that refreshed the page. Probably something wrong with deleting that user when disconnecting. I console.log it when the "like" runs and the user is still there.